# React setState is not updating state with value from firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read a value from firebase database to check if the currently logged in user is an admin or not, but setState is not updating the isAdmin state.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isAdmin: false
    };
}

checkAdmin = () => {
    const self = this;
    const memberId = app.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const memberRef = database
        .ref("members")
        .child(memberId)
        .child("groups")
        .child(this.state.groupid);
    memberRef.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        self.setState({
            isAdmin: snapshot.val().admin
        });
    });
};


componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAdmin();
    console.log(this.state.isAdmin);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it would update asynchronously from your code. Why do you expect it to be synchronous?

Comment: Did you check if the snapshot value is received? setState would update the value if snapshot value is captured.

Comment: console.log(snapshot.val().admin) returns true, but setState does not update